# Which of these parts are LEGO elements?

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands

I have saved up quite a few pieces of "plastic" which I am unsure about - can you tell me which ones are LEGO - I've included plates and a figure for scale.

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

Comment: Just... keep 'em all?

Comment: Thank you for your help editing my post. I have kept them a long time but I now wonder if they are indeed Lego.

Comment: Several of the tools are from playmobil. The first two and the musket definitely are but its hard for me to tell with the rest.

Comment: The last item in the bottom image: could it be a Znap connector?

Comment: Almost always, you can find the word LEGO on true LEGO bricks and pieces. If you can't find it, chances are it ain't LEGO.

Comment: The penultimate one on the second picture is a k'nex (or something like that). you take 2 of these, and you can make a sphere. Not lego.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- **The tools** obviously have different handle widths. If they do not properly fit into a minifigure’s hand, they are almost certainly not Lego. If they do, they are compatible for most practical purposes, even if they are clones.
- **The grey, star-like thing** is a [K’nex connector](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%27Nex).
- **The white post** looks like a [Support 2×2×7 Lamp Post](https://store.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=11062).
- **The left and right part in the bottom image** are nothing I can identify. But they do not look like Lego as their elements do not match the standard Lego scales as seen by the base plate.

Comment: The part on the right in the bottom image is Lego, from the short-lived Znap theme. The part is [Znap Connector 3 x 3 - 4 way](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=Zbb018&idColor=3).

Answer (score 8):

The second gray piece in the bottom image (from left to right) is a [TENTE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tente_(toy)) piece.

Check this example set (look at the feet of the robot)

[image: Example set from TENTE]

Answer (score 3):

Only two LEGO tools are present in the upper image, the [Fabuland shovel](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=x120a) and the [Fabuland pipe wrench](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4328) - other five are Playmobil (1st, 2nd, 5th and 7th in upper row and the rifle in lower row) - the rest, I really don't know - I can't make out the white stick, if it's a [LEGO hose](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&catString=528)

Bottom image seems to have been answered suffiently.